# KeyError in python (GUI)

Tags: python, listbox

I created this GUI which contains a listbox, an entry box and an OK button.

This is the dictionary that is saved into the hard drive (pickled):

```
dict1 = {1: ['Banquet Burger', 80, 19], 
         2: ['Veg Burger', 40, 14], 
         3: ['Chicken Burger', 68, 15], 
         4: ['Cheese Burger', 50, 13]}
```

In the entry widget, when the user enters the product code (key), the item should be inserted into the listbox.

For example if the user types `1` then `'Banquet Burger'` should be added to the list box. If he types `3` the `'Chicken Burger'` should be added to the list (but `'Banquet Burger'` should still be there, it shouldn't disappear).

This code gives me a `KeyError`. I am sure that I imported all the necessary modules.

```
def OK_button():
    with open('Stock Burgers.txt', 'r') as file:
        dict1=pickle.load(file)
        code=product_code.get()
        code1=int(code)
        product_info=dict1[code]
        item=product_info[0]
        items.insert(1, item)

product_code=Entry(mcD, bd=7)
product_code.grid(row=3, columnspan=1)
ok_button=Button(mcD, text='   OK   ', command=OK_button)
ok_button.grid(row=4, columnspan=3)
items=Listbox(mcD, height=10, width=22)
items.grid(row=2, column=0)
mcD.mainloop()
```

Comment: don't use popular tags just for extra attention

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I edited parts of your question to highlight the code and give it more structure - but to reproduce the issue you need to include the specific Exception you've encountered as well as the imported modules. Otherwise it will be hard or impossible for others to help you. Good luck!

Comment: @e4c5 python and listbox are perfect tags since this is python program and i am working with listboxes. So.............I haven't used these tags for extra attention "For ur information".

Comment: @MSeifert Hi!. Thanks for your attention. I have found the issue and have resolved it. Thank you.